# mynodejs login page is not responding

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node js and i tried creating a simple login page. but when i run my code it takes me to the login page alright. the problem is when i enter a user name and password, it doesn't display the information it supposed to display.

```
var express = require('express');
var sessions = require('express-session');

var session;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express(); 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(sessions({
    secret: '2937#&&#',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.get('/login', function(req, resp){
    session = req.session;
    if(session.uniqueID){
        resp.redirect('/redirects');
    }
    resp.sendFile('./files/login.html', {root: __dirname});
});

app.post('/login', function(req, resp){
    // resp.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    session = req.session;
    if(session.uniqueID) {
        resp.redirect('/redirects');
    }

    if(req.body.username == 'admin' && req.body.password == 'admin'){
        session.uniqueID = req.body.username;
    }
    resp.redirect('/redirects');
});

    app.get('/logout', function(req, resp){
        req.session.destroy();
            resp.redirect('/login');
    });

    app.get('/admin', function(req, resp){
        session = req.session;
        if(session.uniqueID != 'admin'){
            resp.end('Unauthorised acess')
        }
        resp.end('You are good');
    })

  app.get('/redirects', function(req, resp){
    session = req.session;
    if(session.uniqueID =='admin') {
        console.log(session.uniqueID)
        resp.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        resp.send(req.session.uniqueID + 'not found <a href="/logout">KILL SESSION</a>');
    }
  })

app.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('Listening at port 1337');
});
```

Comment: Can you give us any logs ?

Comment: In addition to telling us what it doesn't do, tell us what it does.  Does it throw an error?  Does it print anything to console?  Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  Do you get a 404?  Please help us help you.

Comment: yh "Cannot Get"

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because you can't redirect on an AJAX call. Your POST probably works, but then your redirect directive has no effect.

Try sending a "success" response if the username and password are good (a simple `res.send('OK');` would do) and then on the client side redirect the user to `/redirects` (`window.location.replace('https://yoursite.com/redirects'));` if a success code is returned.

This will be handled by your GET route for `/redirects` and you should see what you want.